# How do I color bar charts in Tableau depending on average per pane?

Tags: charts, conditional-formatting, tableau-desktop

[image]

I would like to color the bars per pane depending if they are below or above the average per pane.
I can only achieve this relative to the total average, not relative to the average per pane as shown by the red dotted line...
Is their a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a calculated field called "Color" like this:

```
if sum([Sales]) >= WINDOW_AVG(SUM([Sales]))
then 'greater'
else 'lesser'
end
```

Remember to compute the CF for your more granular field (in this case sub-category), right-clicking on its pill (Compute using).

You should get something like this in the superstore:

[image]